# Android BLE scanning

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

O/S Android 11.
I have developed an application with BLE scanning. It does not do any connection to BLE devices. It just get list of near by devices. App works fine. I can see following error registered in the Logcat each time I stop and start the scan. Can any one please tell me what is wrong.

```
E/BtGatt.GattService: [GSIM LOG]: gsimLogHandler, msg: MESSAGE_SCAN_START, appName: com.ttt.ttt.vctap, scannerId: 11, reportDelayMillis=0
E/BtGatt.GattService: [GSIM LOG]: gsimLogHandler, msg: MESSAGE_SCAN_STOP, appName:com.ttt.ttt.vctap, scannerId: 11, reportDelayMillis=0
```

Answer (score 7):

The two log lines in the question:

`E/BtGatt.GattService: [GSIM LOG]: gsimLogHandler, msg: MESSAGE_SCAN_START, appName: com.ttt.ttt.vctap, scannerId: 11, reportDelayMillis=0`

`E/BtGatt.GattService: [GSIM LOG]: gsimLogHandler, msg: MESSAGE_SCAN_STOP, appName:com.ttt.ttt.vctap, scannerId: 11, reportDelayMillis=0`

do not indicate any error.  They indicate normal operation.

These log lines are specific to Samsung devices.  They indicate that the Android app with applicationId com.ttt.ttt.vctap has started a BLE scan (first line).  The second log line indicates that the scan has been stopped.

Comment: Hi David, Thank you for that.  Since those lines were showing up red. I thought I am doing something wrong the way I was scanning for BLE devices.

Comment: I can't speak to why Samsung chose to make those logs error level.  Some reports indicate that they come from a Samsung package used for watch support.  Regardless, you will make yourself crazy if you try to understand every log line that comes from a closed-source system.  My best advice is not to worry about undocumented log lines unless you notice they are correlated with an actual problem you witness with your app.

Comment: Thanks David. Actually I was going crazy only thinking something wrong with my application.

Comment: anything that can be done to fix this issue? i face this issue in Samsung S21, what all device you tested @Jro ?

Comment: “To fix this issue”?  As stated in the answer, the logs “do not indicate any error. They indicate normal operation.”  You must accept that there are some logs you cannot control, and that sometimes people who write code creating these logs choose the log level poorly.

Answer (score 0):

Try these, after doing this I managed it to work (not everytime but yes)

Steps:

- Bluetooth data clear from system app
- Reset Bluetooth data (network settings)

https://youtu.be/eGNKTeS_iDg

Comment: Answer does not address the log messages asked in the question

Comment: Coz those two are not error and ultimately he needs an answer which will finally work!