# Android BtGatt.GattService stopping and starting and throwing log errors

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to Scan devices with BLE using Kotlin on Android Studio for an Expo Module but the Scan is being turned on and off by itself.

I checked the Logcat and BtGatt.GattService is logging **MESSAGE_SCAN_START** and **MESSAGE_SCAN_STOP** with milisseconds of each other and repeats itself, even thou I only started once.

Also if I try to stop the Scan by myself the events still keeps going as it seems that BtGatt when you fire more than one Scan start the previous start keeps running but your lose its reference.

Here's some more logs: https://pastebin.com/JN9XT7zZ

```
2023-12-01 20:40:11.087 16449-16566 System.out              exp...dules.geonavscaleexpo.example  I  GeonavScaleExpoEvent: started scan
2023-12-01 20:40:11.123 16449-16612 BluetoothAdapter        exp...dules.geonavscaleexpo.example  I  STATE_ON
2023-12-01 20:40:11.127 16449-16612 BluetoothLeScanner      exp...dules.geonavscaleexpo.example  D  Start Scan with callback
2023-12-01 20:40:11.140 25877-26033 BtGatt.GattService      com.android.bluetooth                E  [GSIM LOG]: gsimLogHandler, msg: MESSAGE_SCAN_START, appName: expo.modules.geonavscaleexpo.example, scannerId: 4, reportDelayMillis=0
2023-12-01 20:40:14.162 16449-16612 BluetoothLeScanner      exp...dules.geonavscaleexpo.example  D  Stop Scan with callback
2023-12-01 20:40:14.181 25877-26033 BtGatt.GattService      com.android.bluetooth                E  [GSIM LOG]: gsimLogHandler, msg: MESSAGE_SCAN_STOP, appName: expo.modules.geonavscaleexpo.example, scannerId: 4, reportDelayMillis=0
2023-12-01 20:40:14.215 16449-16612 BluetoothAdapter        exp...dules.geonavscaleexpo.example  I  STATE_ON
2023-12-01 20:40:14.216 16449-16612 BluetoothLeScanner      exp...dules.geonavscaleexpo.example  D  Start Scan with callback
```

The "GeonavScaleExpoEvent" is the logs I'm doing on my actions.

On the full logs I can also see the message:
"2023-12-01 20:40:14.218 25877-25893 BtGatt.GattService      com.android.bluetooth                E  App 'expo.modules.geonavscaleexpo.example' is scanning too frequently"

I'm trying to debug it but what I'm working on have an dependency of an .aar 3rd party lib.

Is there any way to "override" or get an more precise BLE event lifecycle to debug than just looking at logcat?

Also, is seems thats something related to Samsung phones ( [Android BLE scanning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69322378/android-ble-scanning)) but the same devices connects with BLE with other applications and the BluetoothLeScanner and BtGatt does not throw messages of starting and stopping Scan activity causing the same problem.

Any direction would be appreciated.